# Como convertir una consulta MySQL a JSON en C#

Tags: c#, mysql, json, visual-studio

Quisiera saber como convertir el resultado de una consulta MySQL a JSON en C#

No tengo mucho conocimiento en lo siguiente, pero me gustaría que el resultado de la consulta se guardara en JSON.

```
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

    public void GetEmpleadoJSON()
    {
        string server = "localhost", database = "ventas", user = "root", pass = "";
        MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=" + server + "; database=" + database + "; Uid=" + user + "; pwd=" + pass + ";");
        conectar.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = conectar.CreateCommand();

        //consulta select
        command.CommandText = ("SELECT `nombre` FROM `cliente` WHERE id_cliente=901 ");
        command.Connection = conectar;
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        Empleado[] emps = new Empleado[] {
        new Empleado(){
            Id=101,
            Name=reader.ToString(),
            Salary=10000
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(emps));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Rasumus, ¿deseas serializar un `array` de tipo `Empleado[]`, o simplemente un objeto de tipo `Empleado`?

Comment: Hola Flxtr, me gustaria crear un un objeto tipo Empleado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para serializar un objeto requieres hacer uso de la librería `Newtonsoft` con `using Newtonsoft.Json;`:

```
public void GetEmpleadoJSON()
{
    string json = string.Empty;
    Empleado objEmpleado = new Empleado();

    string server = "localhost", database = "ventas", user = "root", pass = "";
    string connectionString = ""server=" + server + "; database=" + database + "; Uid=" + user + "; pwd=" + pass + ";"";

    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT nombre FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente = 901";
            conn.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Empleado.Nombre = (string)reader["nombre"];
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {
                        //Manejo de la excepción
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objEmpleado);
    Context.Response.Write(json);
}
```

Para serializar el objeto es con la línea `json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objEmpleado);`, así sencillito.

De igual forma, si logras notar, he cambiado un poco tu código utilizando contextos `using`, esto es para la liberación de recursos se haga en automático sin tener la necesidad de estar cerrando conexiones a base de datos o liberando recursos de memoria como los comandos o los lectores de la ejecución a base de datos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda, funciono!